# Check if part of file name exists in a path using .net

Tags: vb.net, file, web-applications, file-upload, directory

I would like to check in my weapplication if a file exists in a path provided. File name can be anything eg:pic.jpg, pic.txt,pic1.txt,pic2.jpg etc.
I need to check if "pic" name exists in the path.Only check if 'pic' exists or pic+anything+.jpg or pic.anything.txt exists using vb.net.

Please help.

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to check the [File.Exists](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.exists.aspx) method. Don't forget, this only work for finding files on the server, not the client. Finding a file on the client side is a totaly different mather.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the list of files in the given directory and then check the filenames to see if the fragment of text you're looking for is in any of them. Assuming you want to include the extension in the test and you don't care if it is upper or lower case:

```
Function FilenameFragmentExists(srcDir As String, fragment As String) As Boolean
    Dim files() As String = IO.Directory.GetFiles(srcDir)
    Dim found As Boolean = False
    For i = 0 To files.Length - 1
        If IO.Path.GetFileName(files(i)).IndexOf(fragment, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) > -1 Then
            found = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next

    Return found

End Function
```

Or you can do it in one line with LINQ, and if you are using .NET framework >=4 then you can use `.EnumerateFiles` instead of `.GetFiles`, which has a chance of being faster:

```
Function FilenameFragmentExists(srcDir As String, fragment As String) As Boolean
    Return IO.Directory.EnumerateFiles(srcDir).Any(Function(f) IO.Path.GetFileName(f).IndexOf(fragment, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0)
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use [Directory.GetFiles(path, pattern)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/07wt70x2.aspx) to check if it returns some files corresponding to your pattern. For example

```
Dim files = Directory.GetFiles("C:\temp", "*.jpg")
if files.Length > 0 Then
   Console.WriteLine("Directory contains " + files.Length + " with the required pattern")
Else
   Console.WriteLine("Directory doesn't contain any file with the required pattern")
End if
```

In the second parameter you could pass any kind of pattern following the usual wildcard rules used for directory listing

Comment: Strange, because File.Exists cannot be used with a pattern `File.Exists("C:\temp\pic*.jpg")` return false also if you have pic100.jpg file in that directory